# Android Accelerated emulator keeps rebooting

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I'm used to test application on both real devices and AVD. Since ICS virtual device was very slow, I decided to try the **accelerated emulator**. I followed [instructions](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html) and successfully set up an accelerated virtual machine using Intel Virtualization Technology (x86 system image target).

The emulator works, and it's really fast. BUT at the second app upload/installation, it suddendly reboots. It always **works fine at first startup/upload**, but when I edit something and test the app again, it reboots "from scratch" (showing android logo).

I'm not using snapshots save/restore. LogCat **doesn't report errors**, I'm using Android SDK tools Rev.20 and platform-tools rev. 12, on Win7.

`Intelhaxm` seems to be working properly, reporting "RUNNING" state. After the reboot, I have to upload the app again, that's annoying.

Has anyone encountered the same issue and perhaps solved it?

Comment: Does it reboot when gpu emulation is off?

Comment: I didn't try. How do I shut it off?

Comment: Edit the device and in the hardware features list there should be "GPU emulation", set it to false

Comment: I tried it, still reboots at regular intervals (every 2 updates)

Comment: have you tried updating/reinstalling the emulator and the system image?

Comment: I deleted the virtual device and re-created it, no luck.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of SDK Tools, Revision 20.0.1, claims to have fixed bugs related to emulators using GPU acceleration. Try it after upgrading to the latest verion of SDK tools and ADT.

From the [revision history](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/tools-notes.html):

> Fixed problems with running more than one emulator and running
>   multiple emulators with GPU acceleration.